# How Hide Columns header from material ui table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a set of material ui table header

```
const columns = [
    { id: 'id', label: 'ID', hide: true},
    { id: 'username', label: 'User Name', },
    { id: 'fullname', label: 'Full Name', },
    { id: 'phone', label: 'Phone Name', },
    { id: 'phone', label: 'Phone Name', },
   
  ];
```

So i want to display all field name except ID i tried below code

> ID

my code

```
 {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ top: 57, minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                  hide={column.hide}
                
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
```

Which is not working for me.also tried options: {display: none} not working for me.Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use conditional rendering in your code with a ternary operator. Consider this:

```js
const columns = [
    { ..., hide: true}, // hide this column by using hide: true
    { label: "hello world", hide: false }
    // more columns...
];

const emptyTableCell = <TableCell/>

{ columns.map((column) => (column.hide) ? emptyTableCell : <TableCell>{column.label}<TableCell/>) }
```